# Get resource icon from exe generated from pyinstaller

Tags: python, resources, pyinstaller

I'm generating an .exe using pyinstaller, but I'm not able to include an file without resources.

command line:

`pyinstaller --onefile --icon=./resources/image/icon.ico --add-data="./resources/data.txt;data" ./src/MainGui.py`

When I try to open the file `./data/data.txt` or `data/data.txt` or `data.txt` , it says that the file was not found. The icon was changed sucessfully.

A part of the pyinstaller output:

```
447 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
448 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
448 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
448 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
449 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
449 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
449 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
450 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
454 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
454 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
```

In line 454 says that 0 resources are copying.

Can I print inside the exe file to know the structure?

Comment: remove the quotes